# Copying same range multiple times from one workbook to another

Tags: python, openpyxl

Per the attached image, I am trying to copy and paste the same data into a different format.
I have figured out the first part of the code but I need help abbreviating the 2nd half after this comment:

"Fills in the concepts per store group step by step"

Currently, this code is not efficient and I would like to have it compressed into just a couple of lines.

Image of desired result (Right hand side):

[image: Image of desired result (Right hand side)]

Here is the code I have cobbled together so far:

```
import openpyxl as xl;
filename ="c:\\Users\kevin\Documents\Python Programs\Excel Python\Conceptlist.xlsx"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
# opening the destination excel file
filename1 ="c:\\Users\kevin\Documents\Python Programs\Excel Python\Conceptlist2.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
ws2 = wb2.worksheets[0]

# copying the cell values from source  
# excel file to destination excel file 

rowctsq = ws1['A1']

j = 0
while j < rowctsq.value:
        j = j + 3

        
        for i in range (3 , 6): 
            # reading cell value from source excel file
            # Populates the store list repeatedly
                c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = 1) 

                ws2.cell(row =i , column = 1).value = c.value

                ws2.cell(row =i + j , column = 1).value = c.value

               # Fills in the concepts per store group step by step
        
                c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = 2) 

                ws2.cell(row =i , column = 3).value = c.value
                

                c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = 3) 

                ws2.cell(row =i + 3 , column = 3).value = c.value
             

                c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = 4) 

                ws2.cell(row =i + 6 , column = 3).value = c.value
      

                c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = 5) 

                ws2.cell(row =i + 9 , column = 3).value = c.value


                
   
# saving the destination excel file 
wb2.save('c:\\Users\kevin\Documents\Python Programs\Excel Python\Conceptlist2.xlsx')
```

Comment: I've made some progress here but would love to find a simple way to abbreviate/ shorten the code at the end # Fills in the concepts per store group step by step

Comment: It looks like what you want to do is to transpose the data. You might want to look at using Pandas stack and unstack for this kind of task.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, I get extra community points for answering my own question! I worked through this and have pretty much gotten to my destination. Here's the code I came up with. Works like a charm. :)

```
    import openpyxl as xl;
filename ="c:\\Users\kevin\Documents\Python Programs\Excel Python\Conceptlist.xlsx"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
# opening the destination excel file
filename1 ="c:\\Users\kevin\Documents\Python Programs\Excel Python\Conceptlist2.xlsx"
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
ws2 = wb2.worksheets[0]

# copying the cell values from source  
# excel file to destination excel file 

rowctsq = ws1['A1']


j = 0
k = 0

while j < rowctsq.value and k < 6:
        j = j + 3
        k = k + 1
        
        for i in range (3 , 6):
                
            # reading cell value from source excel file
            # Populates store column
                c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = 1) 

            
                ws2.cell(row =i + j , column = 1).value = c.value
                
        # Populates concept  'x' column

                c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = 1 + k) 
              
   
                ws2.cell(row =i + j , column = 3).value = c.value

        # Populates concept name column

                c = ws1.cell(row = 2, column = 1 + k) 
              
   
                ws2.cell(row =i + j , column = 2).value = c.value 
   
# saving the destination excel file 
wb2.save('c:\\Users\kevin\Documents\Python Programs\Excel Python\Conceptlist2.xlsx')
```

Comment: Didn’t realize there were two people helping me out. Thank you both for the edits.

Comment: Hardcoding row and column values makes this very inflexible. You might find a dictionary based approach: convert each row into a dictionary easiert to work with.

Comment: Hi Charlie, that's a great suggestion. The program is doing exactly what I need it to do now but the dictionary approach will be another valuable method to learn. It may even be better than what I have. Specifically, at this point, I would like the program to automatically multiply the number of rows x columns with values in order to create this transposition. That's the value you see at rowctsq = ws1['A1']. This will allow me to use the program with no further updates even though if my source file changes.